# vue js checkbox state not updated

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vue.js

Hey iam writing piece of code in vue.js. I have problem with checkboxes. I have two of them and they are connected with my backend. They look like this:

```
 <b-form-checkbox 
    v-model="selectedUser.institutionPersonRelations[0].communicationBlocked" @change="editBlockOfCommunication({institutionId:selectedUser.institutionPersonRelations[0].id, profileId:selectedUser.id})">
 </b-form-checkbox>


<b-form-checkbox v-model="selectedUser.institutionPersonRelations[0].uploadBlocked" @change="editUploadBlock({institutionId:selectedUser.institutionPersonRelations[0].id, profileId:selectedUser.id})" :disabled="selectedUser.institutionPersonRelations[0].communicationBlocked == true">
</b-form-checkbox>
```

Everything working correctly until i check second checkbox and then check first checkbox and then uncheck first checkbox. First changing value X and Y in database. Second changing value Y in database. In this case database in updated correctly but second checkbox even if is set to false is still checked, and i need to reload the page to update it.

My backend in php is hit on change event on checkbox looks like that

```
public function editBlockOfCommunicationForProfile(int $institutionPersonId, int $profileId): void
    {
        $entityManager = $this->ormGateway->getEntityManager();
        $profile = $entityManager->find(ProfileDto::class, $profileId);

        if ($profile !== null) {
            $institutionProfile = $profile->getInstitutionPersonRelationWithGivenId($institutionPersonId);
            if ($institutionProfile !== null) {
                if (!$institutionProfile->getDeactivated()) {
                    if ($institutionProfile->getCommunicationBlocked() === false) {
                        $institutionProfile->setCommunicationBlocked(true);
                        $institutionProfile->setUploadBlocked(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $institutionProfile->setCommunicationBlocked(false);
                        $institutionProfile->setUploadBlocked(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * @param int $institutionPersonId
     * @param int $profileId
     */
    public function editUploadBlockForProfile(int $institutionPersonId, int $profileId): void
    {
        $entityManager = $this->ormGateway->getEntityManager();
        $profile = $entityManager->find(ProfileDto::class, $profileId);

        if ($profile !== null) {
            $institutionProfile = $profile->getInstitutionPersonRelationWithGivenId($institutionPersonId);
            if ($institutionProfile !== null) {
                if (!$institutionProfile->getDeactivated()) {
                    if($institutionProfile->getCommunicationBlocked() === false) {
                        if ($institutionProfile->getUploadBlocked() === false) {
                            $institutionProfile->setUploadBlocked(true);
                        } else {
                            $institutionProfile->setUploadBlocked(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $entityManager->flush();
    }
```

Comment: can you provide a working code? on jsfiddle perhaps

Comment: Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ht9rq8qt/ but actual data is from my database (setting true or false) so when you check second checkbox and then first checkbox and then uncheck first checkbox the second is still checked even my change method making correct changes in my database. When i refresh the page the second checkbox is unchecked as it should be.

Comment: Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ht9rq8qt/1/

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly to me. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: after clicking first checkbox second should always be set  to false when you uncheck first checkbox

Comment: to follow changes in my database but you must reload the page after you follow my instructions to get  second checkbox to false, in js fiddle i used data from vue.js i created, in my app i am getting data from database